# Luminous UPS turns off automatically when system left idle

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, battery, shutdown, ups

I have [Luminous UPS](http://www.luminousindia.com). When my UPS is on battery mode and system is idle it automatically turns off my computer. I have made sure it’s not due to low battery because when I start the UPS again it works perfectly fine until my system is idle again.

I am facing this issue with the with Windows 8 and above; currently I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Is the UPS plugged into the computer with USB or alike, or *just* the power plug?  When the system shuts down like this, and you restart, does it think Window shut down properly?

Comment: with power plug and yes window is properly shutdown

Comment: To clarify: Does the UPS shut the system down when idle, or are you saying the the UPS itself shuts off when the system is idle?

Comment: I don't know who shutdown pc or UPS or pc itself. But i think it has something    to do with pc . And window is shutdown and then ups also turn off itself.

Comment: Is your Powersupply compabiitle with your UPS? Many ActivePFC powersupplies are not compatible with the vast majority of UPSs (at least last time I checked). Also, are you 100% sure that it is shutdown, not hibernated?

Comment: How can i make sure of that?

Comment: look up your UPS and your PS models, and do some web research on the specific models.

Comment: @frankthomas well i am not sure i havn't notice that..

Comment: "When my ups is on battery mode and system is idle it automatically turns off my computer." - What exactly is odd about this behavior?  This is the expected behavior when my UPS is running in battery mode.

Comment: @ramhoud so you are saying its normal that automatically shutdown discarding my all work.

Comment: A UPS is not intended to run a system for any length of time but rather allow the OS to perform a proper shutdown to avoid excess data loss. Many applications with unsaved content will have some data loss anyway because they don't properly save and exit when the OS wants to shut down.